# Is it possible to access a database asynchronously through Java NIO non-blocking sockets?

Tags: java, jdbc, real-time, nio

I would like to access a database in a non-blocking way, in other words, I will send the SQL request through a socket and read the query response through the same socket **asynchronously**. That means that I only read data from the socket as it becomes available (Java NIO `SocketChannel`) so I never block.

I might be wrong but as far as I know JDBC drivers for databases all use blocking sockets.

Even if I have to execute a query that returns 1 million lines, I can do that asynchronously, receiving lines as they become available in the socket buffer.

My goal is to execute an SQL query without ever blocking (i.e. without ever producing latency). **Using a separate thread is not an option**. I need to do that inside the network thread (NIO selector thread).

Has anyone succeeded in doing this or can recommend an approach that does not involve an extra thread?

Comment: Why is using a separate thread not an option? It would be quite simple to perform asynchronous queries from another thread.

Comment: @erickson Using another thread is not an option because I don't have a cpu core to spare on my machine for another thread. And that would also not work if you have to do 2 queries simultaneously. The thread would be blocking waiting for the result of the first query to finish. Then you would have to put the second query in a queue or span yet another thread. Doing what I am trying to do implements concurrency in the database side, not on my side. But again, that's a topic for another question. Assume that you are in a job interview and was told that another thread is not an option :)

Comment: You are suffering from some misconceptions about threading. You wouldn't need one core for that thread that is blocked on network I/O. It is not in a *runnable* state, and wouldn't be considered for scheduling on any cores that are available. Most systems successfully run hundreds of threads on a few cores. And doing many asynchronous queries concurrently is not a problem either. That's why database connection pools are a thing.

Comment: @erickson You are suffering from making assumptions about a scenario without knowing anything about the scenario. I can't have 1000 threads doing context switches in few cores because my system is very latency sensitive. I rest my case.

Comment: Which is why I asked, and responded to the information provided.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's possible, but not with JDBC. Unless you want to use the raw `SocketChannel` interface and parse the results yourself, the only async database drivers on the JVM I'm aware of are https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async (which despite the name also supports MySQL). They're written in Scala but it should be *possible* to call them from Java (since it's a JVM language), though I can't say how Java-friendly the API will be.

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware whether the socket protocol for databases is simple to talk so I could perform my queries over the network without using any JDBC driver?

Comment: I don't know that one way or the other.

Comment: It's very possible and easy to call this driver from Java apps. I've been using it for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your own driver, it would certainly be possible to do this for most databases.

I am not aware of any drivers that do this "out of the box," however.