# Java NIO with sql database

Tags: java, sql-server, nio

I am writing a Server using Java NIO that will receive data from client (for eg. location) and will store the data into a database using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I know the call to database is blocking and thus writing codes in the main NIO thread will be to kill all the benefits of NIO.

So how should I proceed?

Another thread to process database requests but how will I send requests to that thread and how will it store them(queue ?) ?

Edit : If anyone suggest using asynchronous DB , please tell one which has good documentation and is supported with java and Microsoft SQL server.

Preferably will like to use JDBC.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128089/is-it-possible-to-access-a-database-asynchronously-through-java-nio-non-blocking) since it seems to be related.

Comment: @Turing85
I have real all questions on stackoverflow relating this none seems to answer my question.Still people think its the same question and down vote.

The question you mention the asker asks for  accessing DB asynchronously and boldly says he can't use any extra threads whereas I never made assumption about any !

Comment: this is why I said **it seems related**. And in regards to the downvote: I did not downvote your question.

Comment: @Turing85 
Thanks for the help.It's till people will down vote and its when I cannot find anything useful on this matter online.

Comment: Explain how you are using NIO? To read data I suppose? So you read from the file system using NIO and write to a DB. How much data are you reading. Is performance really a problem?

Comment: @rghome

No clients are people or devices that connect to server via tcp(socket) and send data then I need to store data into database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to decouple receipt of information to storage in the database then a queue is the normal approach.

Note that all your a really doing is improving response time (deceasing latency) and adding the ability to buffer input to flatten out spikes in the request load. The actual rate at which you can transfer data to the database (throughput) will be the same.

You can use one of the Java `BlockingQueue` implementations in `java.util.concurrent`. These are thread safe.

However,  if you system goes down you will lose any requests in the queue. If that is not acceptable you will need to use a JMS implementation that gives you persistent queues, but you might find that writing to the queue is as slow as writing to the database.

I would first verify whether you really need this decoupling though. The databases are usually pretty fast. You could try reducing the frequency of commits, but again, there is a risk of loss or inconsistency of data.

Comment: Yes ! I did the same and used a `LinkedBlockingQueue`  and used a pool of worker threads to process the DB requests from queue but now the problem I am facing is the DB calls are too slow.

*The client was sending a location so I updated that into the DB but the problem that I am facing now is that the the request are not processed as fast as they are arriving (Queue is filling up fast ) . Any Idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Use multiple database writing threads.  Make sure they don't update any common rows as they will block each other. You may also need to tune SQL Server to have multiple threads/processes managing the requests, but I don't know about SQL Server tuning. EDIT: I maybe misread your comment - you perhaps already have multiple db workers. In this case, it is a db tuning problem. One solution is to use bulk inserts to insert multiple rows at a time. That will speed things up a lot.

Comment: Yes I think the only thing I am left with this is how I use queries (batch update )and DB tuning.

Comment: I tried batch updates and did not help much. Still the problem is database lags from actual data that server has received. I wonder how other are handling this ?

Comment: How much data are you writing (MB/s)?

Comment: How to check that ? By task manager I see I am writing around 1Mb/s into Database .